# Looking fo an API for playback of pre-recorded video content

Tags: playback, video-recording

I want to develop Learning Mgmt system for a Music Academy that can be accessed by students on their Mobile device. Students should be able to learn singing by Repeating after the teacher. FOr a given lesson[uploaded on cloud], when the student clicks on start button of the video player, I wanted following features:
Playback video of teacher singing followed by student repetition section.
• Play/Pause, Progress bar. No Seek functionality.
• Show lyrics with real-time colour fill. Separate colour for teacher and separate for
student.
• Part indicator - Should display ‘Listen’ during teacher’s singing and ‘Sing’ during
student’s part.
• Countdown timer - 3,2,1, Go after teacher and before student part.

I am looking for a ready to use API which can be free or I am ready to purchase if it fits my budget.